# liquibase command line error org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Tags: postgresql, command-line, liquibase

I'm executing the following:

```
liquibase --classpath=./postgresql-42.1.4.jar:./snakeyaml-1.12.jar --changeLogFile=./src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml --username=postgres --password=mysecret --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver update
```

But I'm getting an error

Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

And no other references to why I have the error. How can I know if the snakeyml library I'm using is the appropiate one?

Edit:
Thanks to @bilak  I added --logLevel=debug flag, but still not much info
D

```
EBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Connected to postgres@jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mysdatabase
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Lock Database
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE public.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1)', LOCKGRANTED = '2017-10-31 16:24:07.734' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE
INFO 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Release Database Lock
DEBUG 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE public.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
INFO 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

SEVERE 10/31/17 4:24 PM: liquibase: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml
        at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:23)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1126)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:184)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

So it connects and definitely the error is related to the wrong  org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml I guess 
 1. the classpath is not helping
 2. the version I'm trying to use is not suitable

Comment: try to specify `--logLeve=debug` and see if you can get more informations

Comment: what is liquibase command? Is it deb package on linux or what are you executing under it?

Comment: and also which version of liquibase are you using

Answer (score 2):

The `--classpath` command line argument of liquibase is only used for database drivers, and making snakeyaml available through that does not work.

The `-cp` arg passed to java does work, but the caveat there is that if you also pass `-jar` it will be ignored.

So, you need to do something like:

```
java -cp snakeyaml-1.12.jar:liquibase.jar:sqlite-jdbc-3.34.0.jar liquibase.integration.commandline.Main  --defaultsFile=liquibase.properties --changeLogFile=databaseChangelog.yaml --logLevel debug update
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously snakeyaml.jar needs to be added to classpath somehow.
Neither `--classpath` flag of liquibase nor java's `-cp` did work for me. The fastest way I made it running is by placing driver and yaml jars in **jre/lib/ext/**. 
It was totally fine for me since I was running liquibase within a Docker container